# Does exists a software that act as DHCP service?

Tags: windows, dhcp

I need to configure a network made by a simple old hub with 24-ports a server and some clients.

Both clients and server has Windows XP or later.

If all clients has the **DCHP service enabled** does exists a software that, installed on the server, assigns automatically to the clients an IP based on a predefined range?

Comment: yes, you're looking for *DHCP server* software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DHCP Turbo](http://corporate.weird-solutions.com/products/dhcp-turbo.html) is a fairly simple DHCP server for Windows. However, it is not free.

[Tiny DHCP Server](http://www.softcab.com/dhcp-server/index.php) is another option that I'm sure works well, but I have no experience with it.

You can [search Google for "Windows DHCP Server" to find many more options](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20dhcp%20server).

Comment: I will try the two mentioned this weekend and let you know

Answer (score 1):

why overcomplicate? Internet connection sharing has a simple DHCP server included just set it up as Internet -> server/router running ics -> dumnb hub -> clients, run ICS on the server and you are good.

Comment: Thank you, I will try also your solution. If no software is needed it would better :)

Answer (score 0):

Try also [Tftpd32](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/philippe.jounin/tftpd32.html), it includes a simple DHCP server.